# Cropping a .ppm file in C

Tags: c, file-io, scanf, crop, ppm

I'm working on a C program that crops .ppm files from a starting point pixel (x,y) (top left corner of cropped image) to an end point pixel (x+w,x+h)(bottom left corner of cropped image).

The data in .ppm files is of the following format:

r g b r g b r g b r g b r g b r g b
r g b r g b r g b r g b r g b r g b
r g b r g b r g b r g b r g b r g b
r g b r g b r g b r g b r g b r g b

Is there a simple way, wich avoids the use of 2 dimensional arrays, to do this using scanf()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy way would be to simply keep track of your pixel coordinate as you read the file in. If you're currently in the crop rectangle, store the pixel; otherwise, skip it.

<strike>If you want to get more fancy: figure out the byte offset for the start of each row, seek to it, then read in the whole row.</strike>

Comment: It should be "If you're currently in the crop rectangle, **write** the pixel; otherwise, skip it"

Comment: IIRC the lines are a different length because there is no padding of the values. You would need to scan the entire file and find all the \n to determine the line positions.

Comment: @anatolyg I've changed the word to store which better reflects my meaning.

Comment: @Martin Beckett You're right, I had forgotten that ppm was an ASCII format

Answer (score 0):

Warning, some pnm files are in binary mode (they differ by magic number in the beginning of the file contents).

Maybe lookup the sources of [pnmcrop](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnmcrop.html) would help?